# JVM old geneation keeps increasing while eden and survior are constant

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a java spring boot application which is suppose to be long running and needs response time also < 50ms throughout. Normally we are able to server this but when old gen gets it close to getting filled up, CMS kicks in and our response time SLA breaches. Is there any strategy I can use to ensure that full GC never kicks in.

My server is IO intensive we do not store anything in-memory, but lots of concurrent IOs (30k rpm), each IOs response carriess around 3-4MB of data. From logs I had observed that minor GC ran almost 3-4 times  within a second, minor GC was getting triggered very frequently due to small eden and survivor space (Eden space was 600MB and survivor space 75MB). Due to very frequent GC the objects might be surviving threshold minor GCs(15) , and getting promoted to old gen. So I increased my young gen space by making `-XX:NewRatio=1`.

Still the problem persists I can see Allocation failure log (as below) 3-4 times within a second

`[GC (Allocation Failure) 56455.997: [ParNew: 10705358K->222390K(11796480K), 0.0467254 secs] 13148872K->2667031K(24903680K), 0.0468292 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]`

Using new relic I monitored the memory, young gen is constant while old gen keeps on increasing, below is the snapshot.

[image]

A good heap distribution strategy for my application I think would be where young gen gets filled and emptied continously while old gen is barely used as we hardly have any long lived objects. Please suggest how to achieve the above , or any better strategies you might have in mind

Comment: have you got your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the suggestions:

1. Large obejcts e.g. arrays etc are created the old gen space. So, check for what large objects you are creating and for how long are they staying.
2. Objects are moved to old GC when tenured threshold is met for an object. Hence, you could look in this direction.
3. Check how your minor and major GC are performed as if those are filling quickly or meeting threshold that's when objects are moved to old gen.
4. See the size of your eden and survivor if those are too small those could trigger major gc and cause object moving to old gen.